# How can I link a JToggleButton and a JCheckBoxMenuItem in Java Swing?

Tags: java, swing

How can I do this?
I now try it with 2 ChangeListener and 2 ActionListeners, but it doesn't work.
When I press the button, the checkbox from the MenuItem must be checked...

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

- the shareable piece is a common Action
- the bound property is its value for the SELECTED_KEY

in code, something like

```
Action action = new AbstractAction("shared toggle") {

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        LOG.info("pressed");
    }
};
action.putValue(Action.SELECTED_KEY, Boolean.TRUE);

JPopupMenu menu = new JPopupMenu();
menu.add(new JCheckBoxMenuItem(action));

JComponent box = new JPanel();
box.setComponentPopupMenu(menu);
box.add(new JToggleButton(action));
box.add(new JCheckBox(action));
```

Comment: +1 for sharing the action behind the button instead of the listener approach

Comment: My JToggleButton and JCheckBoxMenuItem are in different classes. Do I have to make a new class for the AbstractAction?

Comment: where they are located doesn't matter: create one instance of the action, then configure the buttons with that same instance.

Comment: Can I use a model with this? Can I make a class that extends AbstractAction and implements ChangeListener?

Comment: @LucPeetersen the questions in your last comment don't make sense to me, sorry. Why would you want to implement a ChangeListener? Go with the action and be happy :-) If that doesn't make sense to you, edit your question with an SSCCE, so we can see what you _really_ want to achieve

Answer (score 1):

You could have them share the same `ButtonModel`. [`setModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#setModel%28javax.swing.ButtonModel%29) and [`getModel`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/AbstractButton.html#getModel%28%29) are defined in `AbstractButton`.

Comment: @kleopatra Care to expand? I thought it was perfectly safe to do so.