# Find all components registered to an action

Tags: java, swing

Is it possible to find all of the `AbstractButton`s to which a certain `Action` has been added? I could keep track, but if the action is already doing the work, I'd rather not duplicate it.

Example:

```
Action action = new AbstractAction() {
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        //set selected state of all registered buttons true
    }
}
AbstractButton item = new JCheckBoxMenuItem(action);
AbstractButton button = new JToggleButton(action);
```

Comment: I don't think so, but the source code will tell you and would be where I'd look if I were in your shoes. What is the driving force behind this recommendation?

Comment: The reason is as i illustrated in that code blurb - when one toggle-able component is marked selected, both should appear selected in the UI

Comment: Couldn't you create a `TrackableAction` or something like that (by extending `AbstractButton`) which stores a reference to every button it gets added to?

Comment: That sounds like a good solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One solution is to have all of the buttons, **whose state must be the same**, share the same ButtonModel:

```
  AbstractButton checkBox = new JCheckBox(myAction);

  AbstractButton toggleBtn = new JToggleButton(myAction);
  toggleBtn.setModel(checkBox.getModel());
```

Comment: This is very helpful. I just found this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9833071/how-can-i-link-a-jtogglebutton-and-a-jcheckboxmenuitem-in-java-swing. I'm thinking too far ahead of myself